# Is it right to load integer first in a0 and then call "li v0, 1"?

Tags: mips

I was reading how to print integers and I made a function:

```
display_int:
 li $v0, 1
 syscall
 jr $ra
```

And I call **display_int** this way:

```
add $a0, $zero, $v0 # load another function result in a0 to print it
jal display_int
```

But every code for display integers writes the code like this: first call **li $v0, 1** and then save some integer in **$a0** and **syscall**. Am I doing it right or should I load the integer after loading a one in $v0?

Comment: It does not matter the order in which you load the registers nor when or how you loaded them. As long as they have the proper values when you issue the `syscall` the result will be the same.

Comment: As gusbro says, order of instructions doesn't matter, as long as the right values are in the right registers at the time of the syscall.  The syscall will look at the registers to see their values: it does not look backward in your instruction stream to see how or when the values got there.

Comment: To "close" it just add your solution as an answer or to your question so that if anyone ever needs to refer to this they can see what you did. Then a member with higher rep can close the question